# How do I find a break in sum formula of ms excel, highlighting the amount summing to non zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having around 10,000 rows of data in excel with positive and negative values, the sum of which is coming to amount say "XXX"

I am expecting a sum to be 'zero'

Now I want to find and highlight the rows which are causing a break (not summing to zero).

Please help me with this regard

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Every time you sum something the end result will change unless your something is 0. Moreover the order by which you are summing numbers might also play a role. Assuming that the values are in column A, in cell B1 you might type =SUM($A$1:$A1) and drag it down till the end you your list. This will show you the partial total for each lane. Since it's a long list you might use conditional formatting to highlights what you want to find. Or sort the list. Or use somethign like =IF(SUM($A$1:$A1)=0,"","X").

Comment: Is there any relation between those 10000 rows? i.e. if there is a value `-42` should there also be a `+42`?

Comment: or, what will be the problem of adding `-SUM(...)` to the last number in this 10000 rows ?

Comment: Yes for some rows there is a relation of -42 +42 and for some rows there is no relation..
all I want to achieve is to highlight the rows which are not summing up to zero.
Or to separate the the rows which are summing up to zero and investigate on rest of them